# How to implement a tickline from kivy.garden in a .kv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to use the Tickline proposed on Kivy-garden to create specific linecharts.
But when I introduce all the parameters in the ".kv", it only draws the main line. I don't find how to generate the ticks.
Furthermore, when I try to modify the "line_width", the main line doesn't change.

Thanks in advance for the help.

I use Python 3.7.2 and Kivy 1.10.1. I tried the 2 solutions shown in the code part.

## This solution only generates the main line, no ticks

```
Tickline:
   orientation: 'horizontal'
   min_index: 0
   max_index: 4
   pos: root.pos
   size: 300, 100
   line_width: 1
   line_offset: 5
   background_color: 1, 0, 1, 0.1
   line_color: 1, 0, 1, 1
   Tick:
        tick_size: 2, 10
        tick_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
        offset: 3
        scale_factor: 1.
        label_global: True
```

## This solution generates an error

```
Tickline:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        min_index: 0
        max_index: 4
        pos: root.pos
        size: 300, 100
        line_width: 1
        line_offset: 5
        background_color: 1, 0, 1, 0.1
        line_color: 1, 0, 1, 1
        ticks: [Tick(tick_size=[4, 20], offset=.5), Tick(scale_factor=5., label_global=True), LabellessTick(tick_size=[1, 4], scale_factor=25.)]
```